# Pronunciation of "nominal" in American English

Tags: pronunciation

I heard the term "nominal" pronounced by a native speaker of American English and I  realised that it was different from the usual British  pronunciation.

I checked in online dictionaries and I found that:

[Nominal](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/pronunciation/english/nominal) (from Oxford  Dictionary)

> - BrE /ˈnɒmɪnl/ ; NAmE /ˈnɑːmɪnl/

while [nominal](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/nominal)  according to the  Cambridge Dictionary:

> - /ˈnɒmɪnəl/ both for British  and American English.

Other online dictionaries also suggest only  the British pronunciation.

What is the correct or most common way to pronounce "nominal" in American English?

Comment: Yes, that makes a difference, does it? I am more familiar with British English.

Comment: There is no difference for American English speakers. See this Wikipedia article: [father-bother merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_low_back_vowels#Father.E2.80.93bother_merger) The phoneme /ɒ/ does not exist in most varieties of North American English. The sound used in "bomb," "nominal," and most other words that have /ɒ/ in British English is /ɑ/ or /ɑː/, the same vowel as in "father" (the length of the vowel is not contrastive).

Comment: The Cambridge Dictionary entry you cited seems to just be an error where they forgot to adjust to the American pronunciation. They transcribe "[nominate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nominate)" as /ˈnɑː.mə.neɪt/.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Is the NAmE pronunciation suggested by the Oxford Dictionary     commonly used by Americans?

Comment: Yes. The transcription of the American pronunciation of "nominal" as /ˈnɑːmɪnl/ is correct. Americans also pronounce "bomb" as /bɑːm/. Both of these words have the same sound as "father" /ˈfɑːðɚ/. It's a different sound from the  British /ɒ/ vowel, used in the British pronunciation of words like "nominal" and "bomb." It's approximately the same as the British /ɑː/ vowel used in words like "farm" /fɑːm/.

Comment: Thanks, is that the common way Americans say 'nominal' or is the British pronunciation also used?

Comment: The British pronunciation would not generally be used. There may be some American dialects and some British dialects where the vowel sounds similar, but normally the American English vowel /ɑː/ or /ɑ/ is unrounded and at the bottom of the vowel chart, while the British vowel  /ɒ/ is more rounded and slightly "higher" on the vowel chart (closer to the sound of /ɔː/ in words like "born").

Answer (score 1):

I'm Canadian but we pronounce most words the same as Americans - although we often tend to use British spellings for words like "colour" - and I've never heard "nominal" pronounced any other way than the following, even in British TV programs or movies:

- "nom" to rhyme with "bomb"
- "in" to rhyme with "tin"
- "ull" to rhyme with "Tull" (as in "Jethro Tull")
- emphasis on the first syllable

Comment: You mean that you have never heard the NAmE pronunciation suggested by the Oxford Dictionaries  ?

Comment: @Saturana: except for a possible small difference in the vowel in the last syllable, that ***is*** the NAmE pronunciation suggested by Oxford Dictionaries. North Americans use /bɑːm/ for *bomb*. The syllabic /l/ and and the syllable /əl/ are allophones, and *Tull* uses /ʌl/, which for many North American speakers is the same vowel as /əl/.